# Insert spaces or breaks on sidebar column - Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have the following mockup flexdashboard:

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
        runtime: shiny
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    ```

    Column {.sidebar}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ```{r}
    selectInput("input_brand", "Select brand:",
                c("Wendy's" = "Wendys",
                  "Burger King" = "BurgerKing",
                  "Big Kahuna" = "BigKahuna"))
    ```


    Column
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Chart A

    ```{r}
    plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Sepal.Width)
    ```
````

I just want to insert some breaks above "Select Brand" input. You can see in the image that the text is close to the "Untitled" bar:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set breaks with the `HTML` function:

**First with br**

````
Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}
HTML("<br><br>") #each <br> is one row

selectInput("input_brand", "Select brand:",
            c("Wendy's" = "Wendys",
              "Burger King" = "BurgerKing",
              "Big Kahuna" = "BigKahuna"))   
```
````

**Second apprach with margin**

````
Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}
div(style = "margin-top: 500px;",
selectInput("input_brand", "Select brand:",
            c("Wendy's" = "Wendys",
              "Burger King" = "BurgerKing",
              "Big Kahuna" = "BigKahuna"))
)
```
````

Comment: It's just what I needed. Thank you @tamtam. Just a question, is it possible to control the height of the break?

Comment: I'm not sure  how to controll the height of <br>, but by defining a top marging of `selectInput` you may achieve a controlled space.

Comment: I appreciate very much your time and answer @tamtam, nice trick using margin-top. Have a great day!